# Combine Columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have the following Pandas dataframe. It is what it is and the input can't be changed.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a', 1,'e', 5],
                             ['b', 2, 'f', 6],
                             ['c', 3, 'g', 7],
                             ['d', 4, 'h', 8]]))
df1.columns = [1,1,2,2]
```

See how the columns have the same name?  The output I want is to have columns with the same name combined (not summed or concatenated), meaning the second column 1 is added to the end of the first column 1, like so:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a', 'e'], 
                             ['b','f'], 
                             ['c', 'g'], 
                             ['d', 'h'], 
                             [1,5],
                             [2,6],
                             [3,7],
                             [4,8]]))
df2.columns = [1,2]
```

How do I do this?  I can do it manually, except I actually have like 10 column titles, about 100 iterations of each title, and several thousand rows, so it takes forever and I have to redo it with each new dataset.

EDIT:  the columns in actual datasets are unequal in length.

Comment: How do you have unequal lengths? Please modify your code to generate that input dataset and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary whose default value is list and loop through the dataframe columns. Use the column name as dictionary key and append the column value to the dictionary value.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

for i, col in enumerate(df1.columns):
    d[col].extend(df1.iloc[:, i].values.tolist())

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').T
```

```
print(df)

   1  2
0  a  e
1  b  f
2  c  g
3  d  h
4  1  5
5  2  6
6  3  7
7  4  8
```

For `df1.columns = [1,1,2,3]`, the output is

```py
   1     2     3
0  a     e     5
1  b     f     6
2  c     g     7
3  d     h     8
4  1  None  None
5  2  None  None
6  3  None  None
7  4  None  None
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `groupby` and `explode`:

```
output = df1.groupby(level=0, axis=1).agg(lambda x: x.values.tolist()).explode(df1.columns.unique().tolist())

>>> output
   1  2
0  a  e
0  1  5
1  b  f
1  2  6
2  c  g
2  3  7
3  d  h
3  4  8
```

###### Edit:

To reorder the rows, you can do:

```
output = output.assign(order=output.groupby(level=0).cumcount()).sort_values("order",ignore_index=True).drop("order",axis=1)

>>> output
   1  2
0  a  e
1  b  f
2  c  g
3  d  h
4  1  5
5  2  6
6  3  7
7  4  8
```

Comment: And if `df1.columns = [1,1,2,3]`, this seems throughing an error.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh - Edited to incorporate the right order. But `explode` does not work if there aren't equal number of values in each list that's created by the `groupby`. OP hasn't mentioned the constraints around their input.

Comment: I guess I should have stated that the columns aren't equal in length.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your data, you could split the data into a dictionary and then create a new data frame from that:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a', 1, 'e', 5],
                             ['b', 2, 'f', 6],
                             ['c', 3, 'g', 7],
                             ['d', 4, 'h', 8]]))
df1.columns = [1, 1, 2, 2]

dictionary = {}
for column in df1.columns:
    items = []
    for item in df1[column].values.tolist():
        items += item
    dictionary[column] = items

new_df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)

print(new_df)
```

Comment: generally you don't need to write loops in pandas. in this case, you definitely don't need your inner loop since you're looping through the elements of a list to put them in another...list

Comment: @PaulH My thinking was that the inner loop was necessary so as not to return the dictionary values in a format like: [['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3'], ['d', '4']]
Though, yes, I'm sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this seems to work:

```py
pd.concat([s.reset_index(drop=True) for _, s in df1.melt().groupby("variable")["value"]], axis=1)
```

Output:

```py
In [3]: pd.concat([s.reset_index(drop=True) for _, s in df1.melt().groupby("variable")["value"]], axis=1)
Out[3]:
  value value
0     a     e
1     b     f
2     c     g
3     d     h
4     1     5
5     2     6
6     3     7
7     4     8
```

Comment: This code does work on my dataset.  It doesn't save the column titles, but those are easily added at the end.  Thanks!

Comment: I copied your dataframe creation code...