# How to combine multiple set of columns in a dataframe to single one?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows

| Cycle | A_0 | A_1 | A_2 | A_3 | B_0 | B_1 | B_2 | B_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |  | 1 | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | 8 | 5 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 8 | 6 | 4 |
| 2 | 7 | 9 | 1 | 6 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 |  | 9 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 8 | 3 |

this dataframe has to combined to two column A and B

**Expected output**

| Cycle | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |  |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | 4 |
| 1 | 6 | 5 |
| 1 | 8 | 0 |
| 1 | 5 | 8 |
| 1 | 3 | 6 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 7 | 1 |
| 2 | 9 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 6 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 |  |
| 3 | 9 | 8 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |

What i did?

```
A = [f"A_{i}" for i in range(20)]
B = [f"B_{i}" for i in range(20)]

df2['A'] = df[A].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
df2['B'] = df[B].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

This line of code is givng me an output datframe by avoiding the nan.
How can i get the expected output?

**ADDON**

**added a new colum to the initial data and expected outcome**

Comment: [Combine Columns in Pandas - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72233876/combine-columns-in-pandas/72233966)

Answer (score 1):

## code part

```
columns = pd.Index(['A_0', 'A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3', 'B_0', 'B_1', 'B_2', 'B_3'], dtype='string')
values = np.array([[ 3.,  4.,  5.,  6., np.nan,  1.,  4.,  5.],
                 [ 8.,  5.,  3.,  1.,  0.,  8.,  6.,  4.],
                 [ 7.,  9.,  1.,  6.,  1.,  0.,  2.,  3.],
                 [ 5., np.nan,  9.,  1.,  0.,  3.,  8.,  3.]],
                dtype=float)
## Or retrive from raw DataFrame if already exists
# columns = df_raw.columns
# values = df_raw.values

## Construct MultiIndex
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((s.split("_") for s in columns))

## Construct DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=mi)

## reshape: stack level=1 (2nd row) of columns to index
df_result = df.stack(level=1)

>>> df_result
       A    B
0 0  3.0  NaN
  1  4.0  1.0
  2  5.0  4.0
  3  6.0  5.0
1 0  8.0  0.0
  1  5.0  8.0
  2  3.0  6.0
  3  1.0  4.0
2 0  7.0  1.0
  1  9.0  0.0
  2  1.0  2.0
  3  6.0  3.0
3 0  5.0  0.0
  1  NaN  3.0
  2  9.0  8.0
  3  1.0  3.0
```

### Explain

Steps:

1. Construct MultiIndex from flat Index

   Pandas provides 4 builtin method to construct MultiIndex;
   Here use from_tuples form
   doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html

   - from_arrays ::
     input `[[x1, x2, ...], [y1, y2, ...]]`
     output `[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ...]`
   - from_tuples ::
     input `[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ...]`
     output same
   - from_frame ::
     Transfer `DataFrames.values` to `MultiIndex`
   - from_product ::
     input like arrays, but zip them to output.
     e.g. input `[[x1, x2], [y1, y2, y3]]`
     output

   MultiIndex([('x1', 'y1'),
   ('x1', 'y2'),
   ('x1', 'y3'),
   ('x2', 'y1'),
   ('x2', 'y2'),
   ('x2', 'y3')],
   )
2. Construct new DataFrame and reshape by stack

   See User Guide on reshape/pivot topic:
   doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=['A', 'B'], i=['index','Cycle'], j='x', sep='_')
   .droplevel(['index', 'x'])
 )
```

Output:

```
         A    B
Cycle          
1      3.0  NaN
1      4.0  1.0
1      5.0  4.0
1      6.0  5.0
1      8.0  0.0
1      5.0  8.0
1      3.0  6.0
1      1.0  4.0
2      7.0  1.0
2      9.0  0.0
2      1.0  2.0
2      6.0  3.0
3      5.0  0.0
3      NaN  3.0
3      9.0  8.0
3      1.0  3.0
```

Comment: got this error: *KeyError: "['index'] not in index"*

Comment: What is the full error? Does your index have a name in the real dataset? Then you need to adapt to use this name instead of "index"